# How can I control the flow of messages in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Suppose we have a client application which sends requests to a server using `NetTcpBinding` and receives replies through callbacks. How could the client be aware that he was sending too many requests? Or how could it see that the connection (over which it sends requests) is slow?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at WCF throttling. There is a question on SO talking about it here:-
[Service too busy error in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900616/service-too-busy-error-in-wcf)