# Why my *Timeout settings are ignored?

Tags: c#, wcf

My solution contains two projects: WCF services and WCF client. The order of launching:

[image]

When I manually launch my service and later my client it works fine. But if I do the same through IDE in the Debug mode then time of time I get the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   `System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException` occurred in
>   `mscorlib.dll`
>
> **Additional information:** Listening on `net.pipe://localhost/` wasn't
>   executed by any ending point who could accept the message. Among other
>   causes it could be caused by the wrong address or action of SOAP. For
>   more details see in the description of InnerException (*if is
>   available*).

But my client's `Config`-file contains timeout settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <netNamedPipeBinding>
            <binding
                     closeTimeout="00:30:30"
                     openTimeout="00:30:30"
                     receiveTimeout="00:30:30"
                     sendTimeout="00:30:30"/>
          </netNamedPipeBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint name="pipe1"
                    address="net.pipe://localhost"
                    binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                    contract="ServiceReference1.IContent"/>

          <endpoint name="pipe2"
                    address="net.pipe://localhost"
                    binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                    contract="ServiceReference1.IMessages"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Why the exception occur time of time in the Debug mode?

**UPD**

Additional variant of the decission:

```
#if DEBUG
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
#endif
```

Comment: I guess the client is trying to connect too soon. You could surround the connecting code with some retry mechanism (i.e. wait for x milliseconds and try again, repeat y times, throw exception when connecting does not succeed after y tries).

Comment: Probably related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340521/how-can-i-make-named-pipe-binding-reconnect-automatically-in-wcf).

Comment: but the exception occurs earlier than 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not actually ignored, it is the [expected behaviour](http://www.rauch.io/2015/06/25/all-wcf-timeouts-explained/)  :

> Note: if a connection to the service endpoint cannot be established at
>   all (i.e. the service is not reachable), WCF does not throw a
>   TimeoutException, instead, the framework throws an
>   EndpointNotFoundException – immediately.

I am not sure whether there is a way to do it properly (at least I can't find anything standard - [Time taken to throw EndPointNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007972/time-taken-to-throw-endpointnotfoundexception)), but you can always create your own on-error reinitialization mechanism (the simplest, but not the best solution is to just catch the `EndpointNotFoundException` and try to reinitialize the client later).

Comment: I added  UPD section.